# Work using a single aws account with separate teams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to work with my colleagues using a single AWS account. And also I should give permission to each colleague separately. It means I should give different permission for each of them.

For now, I am thinking of creating a separate IAM user for each one. **Instead of achieving this through IAM user, can I achieve this using IAM user and role?**  Then I can assign IAM roles when needed. But I have only one AWS account.

Comment: Yes, you want your collaborators to be separate IAM users (the alternative is to have them log in with *YOUR* username and password - a Bad Idea!).  And yes, you want to create IAM roles, and assign AWS permissions based on the roles.  Look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html

Comment: IAM users are the way to go. From your question it's not clear where is your problem. You may assign permissions directly to a user or (better) to a group and assign the users to their groups

Answer (score 1):

The typical method is:

- Assign an **IAM User** to each staff member who needs access
- Assign IAM Users to **IAM Groups** to grant permissions to *groups* of users (by assigning permission to the IAM Group)
- Assign permissions to individual IAM Users if they do not fit a standard IAM Group
- Use **IAM Roles** for AWS services that require permissions (eg Amazon EC2 instances)
- If appropriate, allow IAM Users to *assume* an IAM Role if they temporarily need additional access (eg temporarily assuming Admin permissions)

Based on your description, you should use **IAM Groups** to assign standard permissions to users rather than using IAM Roles. This is because it takes extra steps to gain the permissions from an IAM Role (the user needs to "assume" the role), so it is not a good method to assign permissions to a user for normal use.

Comment: I forgot about the importance of "IAM Groups".  You're absolutely correct, on all points.